# Merging two JSON objects with jq

Tags: json, object, merge, jq

I have two json files, each containing one simple object, for example:

*file1*

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

*file2*

```
{
    "key1": "valueA",
    "key3": "valueB"
}
```

I need to combine these two using jq so that I end up with one object that contains all of the keys from both objects. If there are common keys, I need the values of from second object being used.

I'm struggling to get the right expression to use. I thought that something as simple as

```
jq '. * .' file1 file2
```

should give me what I want, however this results in a non-json output:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
{
    "key1": "valueA",
    "key3": "valueB"
}
```

The same exact thing happens if I use `jq '. + .' file1 file2`.

How can I combine these two objects?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By passing in multiple input files, the contents of each file are streamed in. You'd either have to slurp them in or combine the individual inputs.

```
$ jq -s 'add' file1 file2
```

or

```
$ jq -n 'reduce inputs as $i ({}; . + $i)' file1 file2
```

Or if you wanted to merge instead of add.

```
$ jq -n 'reduce inputs as $i ({}; . * $i)' file1 file2
```

Comment: Ah! This is it, thanks so much.  With the merging, are values from the second one override values from the first or vice versa?

Comment: I believe the second takes precendence. Merging is useful for deeply nested objects. But your input seems to be shallow.

Comment: Correct, shallow inputs. Thanks again.

Comment: Hm... interesting.  I tried using the last one option. It works fine on my MacOS box, but fails on linux: `error: inputs is not defined <newline>
reduce inputs as $i ({}; . * $i)       1 compile error`

Comment: You must be using an older version of jq. `inputs` was added in 1.5 I believe.

Comment: Yep, that was it - 1.4 (whatever was installed from standard repo on debian 7 - I don't have much control over it).  I'll try other options.

Comment: You should definitely try to get 1.5 at a minimum. There's a lot of features there that makes jq much more useful and extensible. If not from your distro, build it or get the binaries.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way with **jq** `--slurpfile` option:

```
jq --slurpfile f2 file2 '. + $f2[0]' file1
```

The output:

```
{
  "key1": "valueA",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "valueB"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way (assumes sample data in `file1.json` and `file2.json`):

```
$ jq -Mn --argfile file1 file1.json --argfile file2 file2.json '$file1 + $file2'
{
  "key1": "valueA",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "valueB"
}
```